# IOS ::: No suitable image URL loader found for assets-library://asset/asset

Tags: image, react-native-ios

using React native in IOS at this code :

```
<ImageBackground
                  style={styles.item}
                  source={{ uri: item.uri }} >
                  {selected && selectedItemCount.lenght > 0 &&
                      <View style={{ ...styles.countBadge, backgroundColor: badgeColor }}>
                          <Text style={styles.countBadgeText}>{selectedItemCount}</Text>
                      </View>
                  }
              </ImageBackground>
```

item.uri is : assets-library://asset/asset.PNG?id=8602ACD9-04C2-4FA9-B8A1-F65E1C1299DD&ext=PNG

it work at andriod but IOS comes with this error :

> [tid:com.facebook.react.ImageLoaderURLRequestQueue][RCTImageLoader.mm:510] No suitable image URL loader found for assets-library://asset/asset.PNG?id=8602ACD9-04C2-4FA9-B8A1-F65E1C1299DD&ext=PNG
>   2020-06-08 23:16:28.129

react version : "react-native": "~0.61.5",
xcode version : 11.4.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so it seems they changed it from assets-library://asset/ to ph://  so becouse i was using the expo media library  i changed it to native cameraroll it works but spuriously it is not working for video the video still using old assets-library